# Removing double space and single space in data frame simultaneously

Tags: pandas

I have a column where the names are separated by Single space, double space(there can be more) and I want to split the names by Fist Name and Last Name

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Steve  Smith', 'Joe Nadal', 
                           'Roger   Federer'],{'Age':[32,34,36]})

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.strip()


df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = df['Name'].str.split(" ",expand = True,)
```

Comment: @anky_91 hey any specific reason to del the answer ?

Comment: split with `\s+` instead..?

Comment: the error i am getting is Columns must be same length as key. There are multiple spaces in between the name and it is not constant

Comment: Adding one more thing, what if i have a middle name as well in some rows . Will the above solution change

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
 df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] =  df.Name.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list((filter(None, x.split(' '))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s+` as your split pattern. This is the regex pattern meaning *"one or more whitespace characters"*.

Also, limit number of splits with `n=1`. This means the string will only be split once *(The first occurance of whitespace from left to right)* - restricting the output to 2 columns.

```
df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = df.Name.str.split('\s+', expand=True, n=1)
```

[out]

```
              Name  Age First_Name Last_Name
0     Steve  Smith   32      Steve     Smith
1        Joe Nadal   34        Joe     Nadal
2  Roger   Federer   36      Roger   Federer
```